# Getting SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap from Texture2D

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

I'm trying to create an off-screen bitmap to draw on it and to draw it with `Direct2D1.RenderTarget.DrawBitmap` then. So I create `Texture2D` and get the Bitmap from it. But I receive the error

```
[D2DERR_UNSUPPORTED_PIXEL_FORMAT/UnsupportedPixelFormat]
```

in last string of code. Please help me to understand, what have i done wrong here?

```
    m_texture = new Texture2D(
            context.Device,
            new Texture2DDescription() {
                ArraySize = 1,
                BindFlags = BindFlags.RenderTarget | BindFlags.ShaderResource,
                CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
                Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
                Height = bitmapSize.Height,
                Width = bitmapSize.Width,
                MipLevels = 1,
                OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription() {
                    Count = 1,
                    Quality = 0
                },
                Usage = ResourceUsage.Default
            }
        );

        m_surface = m_texture.QueryInterface<Surface>();

        using (SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory factory = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory()) {
            m_renderTarget = new RenderTarget(
                factory,
                m_surface,
                new RenderTargetProperties() {
                    DpiX = 0.0f, // default dpi
                    DpiY = 0.0f, // default dpi
                    MinLevel = SharpDX.Direct2D1.FeatureLevel.Level_DEFAULT,
                    Type = RenderTargetType.Hardware,
                    Usage = RenderTargetUsage.None,
                    PixelFormat = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(
                        Format.Unknown,
                        AlphaMode.Premultiplied
                    )
                }
            );
        }

        m_bitmap = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap(m_renderTarget, m_surface);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you specify a pixel format?

Comment: if i shold to do it so where can i do it? actualy i got a solution already. i nead to create BitmapRenderTarget from this RenderTarget, and to obtain Bitamp from it then. it woks that way, but i cant understand exactly what i'v done wrong previously

Comment: Well if you're getting Unsported pixel format, and you're declaring your PixelFormat as Format.Unknown. You might try one of these formats: http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/t-sharpdx-wic-pixelformat ...At first glance that's what I would assume. But if you have a working solution, awesome!

Comment: Iv been trying the same pixel format the m_texture uses, but result was the same. So i chose Unknown, because the system selects the same format the m_surface uses. The question actually is: why should i create BitmapRenderTarget instead simply using RenderTarget and what the difference between BitmapRenderTarget and RenderTarget in common and in lower level implementation?

Comment: And what the Bitmap constructors really does and how should they be use?

Comment: A bitmap render target is for using it with a bitmap brush, or caching drawing data that will be used repeatedly. So if you're gonna use a tile set for a map, you could use it for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
  public static SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap GetBitmapFromSRV(SharpDX.Direct3D11.ShaderResourceView srv, RenderTarget renderTarger)
    {
        using (var texture = srv.ResourceAs<Texture2D>())
        using (var surface = texture.QueryInterface<Surface>())
        {
            var bitmap = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap(renderTarger, surface, new SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapProperties(new SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(
                                                      Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
                                                      SharpDX.Direct2D1.AlphaMode.Premultiplied)));
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
```